# How to change ES6 imported array

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, import, module

So I have a app built using ES6 modules, I want to clear an array imported as a module in one file and add to it from another file. Pushing to the array works fine, but I can't empty the array in a delete function. Debugging wise the function is called and I get no errors but the array is not cleared.

The array clears if it is included in the same module as the clear function...

below is an example.

```
    module_1.js
    export let array = [];


//////////////////////////////////////////////////


    module_2.js 
    import { array } from './module_1.js';

    export const func = () => {array.push('hello')};


//////////////////////////////////////////////////

    module_3.js
    import { array } from './module_1.js';

    export const clear = () => {
     let array = [];
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////

   module_4.js
   import { array } from './module_1.js';
   import { func } from './module_2.js';
   import { clear } fromt './modeule_3.js';

   button.addEventListener('click', func);
   button.addEventListener('click', clear);
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot reassign a module variable outside of the module where it was declared, even if was defined using `let` or `var`.

So, this:

```js
//module1.js
export let foo = 'bar'

foo = 'baz'
```

```js
//module2.js
import {foo} from './module1.js'

console.log(foo) //baz
```

...works, while this:

```js
//module1.js
export let foo = 'bar'
```

```js
//module2.js
import {foo} from './module1.js'

foo = 'baz' //TypeError

console.log(foo)
```

...does not.

However, mutation of objects is still allowed, that's why `.push()` works in your second module.

To solve the problem, you have to either:

1. Empty the array using mutation

   You can empty an array by setting its `length` to zero, but this still modifies a module's data from outside, which isn't the best practice...

   ```
   //module_3.js
   import { array } from './module_1.js';

   export const clear = () => {
       array.length = 0;
   }
   ```
2. Move all mutator methods to a single module

   ```
   //module_1.js
   export let array = [];

   export const func = () => {
       array.push('hello')
   };

   export const clear = () => {
       array = [];
   }
   ```

   ```
   //module_2.js
   import { func, clear } from './module_1.js';

   button.addEventListener('click', func);
   button.addEventListener('click', clear);
   ```
3. Create general-purpose functions

   ```
   //module_1.js
   export let array = [];

   import {func as _func} from './module_2.js';
   export const func = () => _func(array)

   import {clear as _clear} from './module_3.js';
   export const clear = () => _clear(array)
   ```

   ```
   //module_2.js
   export const func = (array) => {
       array.push('hello')
   };
   ```

   ```
   //module_3.js
   export const clear = (array) => {
       array.length = 0;
   }
   ```

   ```
   //module_4.js
   import { func, clear } from './module_1.js';

   button.addEventListener('click', func);
   button.addEventListener('click', clear);
   ```

Comment: That's brilliant thanks. I managed to find a way around it earlier today anyway. The arrays are stored inside of an object so I found I can clear them like so. 

`someObject[array] = [];`

Answer (score 0):

In module_3.js you are redeclaring the array variable as let, this will define a local variable scoped to the clear function, removing let will give you the expected result.

```
export const clear = () => {
   array = [];
};
```

Comment: I did think that but when I tried to import the array and call it without a declaration I get.
Uncaught TypeError: Assignment to constant variable.